# Can anyone identify this locust / grasshopper in Florida, USA?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found in Pinellas County, Florida

[image: Locust]
[image: Locust]
[image: Locust]

Comment: Can you add some more details about it, including some more images?

Comment: Two more images added. What other details would you like?

Comment: @Stewart, for future reference, see the [guide for writing species ID questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) -- it'll tell you what info is typically needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be *Romalea microptera*, or the eastern lubber grasshoper, which is commonly found in the southeastern United States, including Florida.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romalea_microptera
http://eol.org/pages/965190/overview

[image]
Photo by Steve Smith.

Answer (score 0):

Eastern lubber , although they get to TX. Kill it , if you have any bulb type flowers . They will eat all amaryllis leaves and the whole bulb. The immature are gloss black with red pinstripes ; so pretty I made the mistake of not killing them one year.